# How to resolve @bazel_tools//tools/android:databinding_exec when switching from bazel 3.6.0 to 3.7.0

Tags: android, build, bazel, toolchain

I’ve been using bazel to build an android project, initially starting with a 0.24 version, then using the 2.0 version for a longer time, and now I am trying to switch to the latest 3.7.0 / 3.7.1 versions.

Currently I am using the following important .bazelrc settings for android:

```
build:androidbuild --crosstool_top=@androidndk//:default_crosstool
build:androidbuild --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain
build:android-32 --config=androidbuild --cpu=x86 --fat_apk_cpu=x86
```

All **cc_binary** / **cc_library** targets can still be built the same way we used to, but the **android_binary** targets no longer builds and I am getting this error:

> ERROR: While resolving toolchains for target
> @bazel_tools//tools/android:databinding_exec: No matching toolchains
> found for types @bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type. Maybe
> --incompatible_use_cc_configure_from_rules_cc has been flipped and there is no default C++ toolchain added in the WORKSPACE file? See
> https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10134 for details and
> migration instructions.

I tried to find which was the bazel version that started to throw this error, and I found that I can still build my project with 3.6.0, but I start getting the above error if I switch to 3.7.0 or 3.7.1.

Looking at the 3.6.0 vs 3.7.0 changes, I am wondering if the new **create_dummy_sdk_toolchain** call in **tools/android/android_sdk_repository_template.bzl** would cause this failure or there is something else I am missing (like changes in the **cc_flags_supplier.bzl** / **compiler_flag.bzl** sources to set **incompatible_use_toolchain_transition** to **True**).

I tried the approach of using **--platforms** instead, but I am still getting errors even in that case:

```
build:androidbuild --extra_toolchains=@androidndk//:all
build:android-32 --config=androidbuild --cpu=x86 --platforms=//config:android_x86
```

With:

```
platform(
    name = "android_x86",
    constraint_values = [
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_32",
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:android",
    ],
    cpu_constraints = [
    ],
    os_constraints = [
    ],
    target_platform = True,
)
```

Error:

> ERROR: While resolving toolchains for target
> @bazel_tools//tools/android:instrumentation_test_check: No matching
> toolchains found for types @bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type.
> Maybe --incompatible_use_cc_configure_from_rules_cc has been flipped
> and there is no default C++ toolchain added in the WORKSPACE file? See
> https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10134 for details and
> migration instructions.

Can you please advise me on what is missing from the project that is required to solve the problem caused by the 3.6.0 vs 3.7.0 diffs, do we now need to define a proper toolchain for Android (can't we rely anymore on bazel to figure out how to build android targets)?

**UPDATE Dec/16/2020**

Looks like the problem was caused by this code:

WORKSPACE:

```
register_execution_platforms(
    "//tools/config:host_platform",
)
```

In the BUILD file:

```
platform(
    name = "host_platform",
    constraint_values = [
    ],
    cpu_constraints = [
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_32",
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_64",
    ],
    host_platform = True,
    os_constraints = [
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:windows",
    ],
)
```

For some reason this works in bazel 3.6.0 even when the host is Linux, but it's no longer working in 3.7.0.

Comment: I tried to repro this with bazel 3.7.1, and it seemed to work, even with an app with databinding. Can you give any repro instructions? What happens when you try `bazel --bazelrc=/dev/null build @bazel_tools//tools/android:databinding_exec`? What happens without `--bazelrc=/dev/null`?

Comment: > `do we now need to define a proper toolchain for Android`, for what it's worth, this sort of error shouldn't be happening out of the box

Comment: @ahumesky I tried both commands (with and without .bazelrc) with 3.6.0 and 3.7.0 and they all worked, I haven't seen any relevant changes other than the different progress reporting style during the build (which is probably explained by some other 3.7.0 changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by this code:

WORKSPACE:

```
register_execution_platforms(
    "//tools/config:host_platform",
)
```

In the BUILD file:

```
platform(
    name = "host_platform",
    constraint_values = [
    ],
    cpu_constraints = [
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_32",
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_64",
    ],
    host_platform = True,
    os_constraints = [
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:windows",
    ],
)
```

For some reason this works in bazel 3.6.0 even when the host is Linux, but it's no longer working in 3.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

when I do bazel build --platforms=//:linux_arm64 it gave me the same error:
hile resolving toolchains for target @io_bazel_rules_go//:cgo_context_data: No matching toolchains found for types @bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type. Maybe --incompatible_use_cc_configure_from_rules_cc has been flipped and there is no default C++ toolchain added in the WORKSPACE file? See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10134 for details and migration instructions.

The follow command works
bazel build --platforms=@io_bazel_rules_go//go/toolchain:linux_arm64